# Eigenmode problem of Maxwell's equations, verification.

Tags: vector-analysis, finite-element-method

According to https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S004578250200539X?via%3Dihub

> We are interested in finding solutions to Maxwell's equations which propagate along the source-free waveguide. The general ansatz for such fields is given by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \mathbf{E}\left(\boldsymbol{x}, x_3, t\right)=\left(\boldsymbol{E}(\boldsymbol{x}), E_3(\boldsymbol{x})\right) e^{\jmath\left(\omega t \mp \beta x_3\right)}, \\
> & \mathbf{H}\left(\boldsymbol{x}, x_3, t\right)=\left(\boldsymbol{H}(\boldsymbol{x}), H_3(\boldsymbol{x})\right) e^{\jmath\left(\omega t \mp \beta x_3\right)},
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where $\boldsymbol{x} \in \Omega$ and the $x_3$-axis is along the waveguide. The positive number $\omega$ denotes frequency, and $\beta$ is the constant of propagation. $\boldsymbol{E}$ and $\boldsymbol{H}$ are electric and magnetic field components in the plane of the cross section, and $E_3$ and $H_3$ are electric and magnetic components along the waveguide. With ansatz (2.1), the second order 3D Maxwell equations expressed in terms of electric field $\left(\boldsymbol{E}, E_3\right)$ alone reduce to three 2D equations:
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \boldsymbol{E}\right)-\omega^2 \epsilon \boldsymbol{E}+\frac{\beta^2}{\mu} \boldsymbol{E}-\frac{\jmath \beta}{\mu} \nabla E_3=0 \\
> \boldsymbol{\nabla} \circ\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \nabla E_3\right)+\omega^2 \epsilon E_3+\jmath \beta \nabla \circ\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{E}\right)=0 \\
> \boldsymbol{\nabla} \circ(\epsilon \boldsymbol{E})-\jmath \beta \epsilon E_3=0
> \end{array}\right.
> $$

However I am not able to get $$\nabla \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \nabla \times E\right)-\omega^2 \epsilon E+\frac{\beta^2}{\mu} E-\frac{\mathrm{j} \beta}{\mu} \nabla E_3=0$$

Especially the term $\frac{\beta^2}{\mu} E$. My confusion is that if $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \mathbf{E}\right)= \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times E'\right) + \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times E_3'\right)$, where $E' = (E_1, E_2, 0)$ and $E'_3 = (0, 0, E_3)$, the term $\frac{\beta^2}{\mu} E$ seems to come from nowhere.

Comment: Did you forget the $\exp(\jmath\left(\omega t \mp \beta x_3\right))$?

Comment: but since $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times E^{\prime}\right)$ is kept as $\nabla \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \nabla \times E\right)$, from $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times\left(\frac{1}{\mu} \boldsymbol{\nabla} \times E_3^{\prime}\right)$ how can you get $\frac{\beta^2}{\mu} E$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's stick with the notation in the article.

Our ansatz:
\begin{align*}
\mathscr{E}(\mathbf{x},x_3,t)&=(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\jmath(\omega t\mp\beta x_3)}\\
\mathscr{H}(\mathbf{x},x_3,t)&=(\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{x}),H_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\jmath(\omega t\mp\beta x_3)}
\end{align*}

Then second-order Maxwell
$$\require{cancel}
\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\nabla\times\mathscr{E})
+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\epsilon\mathscr{E}=0
$$
gives (at $t=0$, using the identity $\nabla\times(\psi\mathbf{A})=\psi\nabla\times\mathbf{A}+(\nabla\psi)\times\mathbf{A}$)
\begin{align*}
0&=
\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})-\omega^2\epsilon((\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\\
&=\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\bigg(
e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))
+
\underbrace{(\nabla e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})}_{\parallel\mathbf{e}_3}\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),\cancel{E_3(\mathbf{x})})
\bigg))\\
&\quad-\omega^2\epsilon((\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\\
&=\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\bigg(
e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))
\mp\jmath\beta e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0)
\bigg))\\
&\quad-\omega^2\epsilon((\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\\
&= e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x})))+(\nabla e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\times\frac1\mu
\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x})))\\
&\quad
\mp\frac{\jmath\beta}{\mu}\bigg(
(\nabla e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\times(\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0))
+ e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0))
\bigg)\\
&\quad-\omega^2\epsilon((\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})\\
%%%%%
&= e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\frac1\mu\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x})))\mp\jmath\beta e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\mathbf{e}_3\times\frac1\mu
(\nabla\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))))\\
&\quad
\mp\frac{\jmath\beta}{\mu}\bigg(
\mp\jmath\beta e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\underbrace{\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0))}_{=-(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0)}
+ e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}\nabla\times(\mathbf{e}_3\times(\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),0))
\bigg)\\
&\quad-\omega^2\epsilon((\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}),E_3(\mathbf{x}))e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3})
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{e}_3$ is the unit vector in the $x_3$ direction.  Now you can take out the $e^{\mp\jmath\beta x_3}$ and I'll leave the rest of the simplification to you.

Comment: $\nabla \times(\psi \mathbf{A})=\psi \nabla \times \mathbf{A}+(\nabla \psi) \times \mathbf{A})$ reminds me of basic curl rules, thank you so much!